# Save as a blank html page instead of content

Tags: html

I am using asp.net web form and the content is displayed let just say in the about-us.aspx.

I know it is impossible to disable Save As option in the browser file menus, but is it possible to have users saving it as a blank HTML page instead of the content?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could disable the "save as" feature, which... no, you can't. But say for an instant you could. Anyone who wanted (a copy of your webpage) could just take a screen shot and print that. Or, they could open the source code and copy/save that. Saving the file isn't the only way that they can grab your content. 
Is there a reason that you don't want them to copy it?
Are you trying to prevent people (in general) from seeing the page?
If there is some other consideration, please leave a comment so we can expand on this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Generally and yes you are right, users would still be able to take screenshots and source code. What I have implemented so far is disable right click and disable highlighting of the content through code behind. All I want to achieve is to make things a bit difficult for copying web content. I have read somewhere where a user was trying to save as HTML page from a SAAS but ended getting a blank page.  I am not sure whether is possible or not. Thanks a lot and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, I could be way off base.. don't tell my son, but every once in a while, (a long while,) I'm "not right".  ;)  Let me know if you ever find out otherwise.


ooo... Don't forget about all of those browsers that allow you to click on a "developer's view", exposing everthing about the page. Clearly you cannot change a site visitor's browser selection/settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is at least what I could came up with. I used the window.open without toolbar and menubar and full screen and it seems due to security reasons, the modern browser would not let you hide the address bar.. So in order to prevent copy and paste the url, I used the http referrer to detect copy and paste. I also disabled the context menu and hightlghting the content. So far it works well with chrome based browser like edge, opera but not firefox. So what I did next is to restrict browser that are not chrome based. Thanks a lot.